# Table didSelect method not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a problem while selecting a row in a tableView, the problem is that when I select a row for a first time it get highlighted with gray but nothing happens, and I have to select again a row to execute the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and takes me to an other ViewController

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Data
    NSLog(@"row selected %d", (int)indexPath.row);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you kept `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` ,replace with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: You saved my day ^^ I did the same mistake :p